# Where should I post a question about which graphics/video card to get?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a severely outdated graphics card, so I need a new one. I was going to ask on SuperUser, but I read their FAQ and it said to not ask questions about "a shopping or buying recommendation." I found [a post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) explaining that, and the example was:

> **However**, there *is* a way to ask these questions that avoids the
> inherent problems with shopping recommendations. For example, let’s
> say you wanted — as I did — to buy a point-and-shoot camera that takes
> good low light photos. So we’re going to ask on
> [photo.stackexchange.com](https://photo.stackexchange.com/), naturally!

However, I couldn't find a "graphics.stackexchange.com" or "video.stackexchange.com" or anything like that. Where should I ask my question?

Comment: Shopping recommendations are off-topic on every known SE site AFAIK

Comment: @juergend what about the quote in my question? also, [link](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1373/how-do-i-tell-which-point-and-shoot-cameras-take-good-low-light-photos) and [link](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: @Doorknob Given how you've phrased the title of this meta question, you've clearly not properly formatted such a question yet.  The whole point is that none of the answers would contain any actual products, merely some facet of information you should look for in buying products that meet that need.

Comment: @Servy okay, that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd still ask on Super User, you'd just change the question so it would be of the form:

> How do I tell which point-and-shoot cameras take good low light photos?

Instead of asking for shopping recommendations, you need to ask how to tell which graphics cards have the specific features you're looking for.  That way you're *learning how* to shop for a graphics card instead of just asking everyone for their current favorite.

Comment: Alright, I'll do that. Thanks! (I can accept this in 8 minutes)